# How to install Maven archetype from local JAR and POM, and also update local catalog

Tags: maven

I want to distribute a custom archetype JAR and POM, without deploying them to a Maven repository, so that someone can grab them and install in their local repository with something like a `mvn install:install-file -Dfile <file> -DpomFile <pom>`.

But if one just does:

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./my-archetype-1.0.jar -DpomFile=./my-archetype-1.0.pom

the local catalog doesn't get updated.

Though there are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089419/install-maven-archetype), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406652/install-maven-archetype-project-jar-with-pom-file-to-local-repo)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499873/how-to-use-my-custom-archetype-with-maven), they left me missing a small step.

I'm not sure how to run the `mvn archetype:update-local-catalog` that they mention.   Where's the **pom.xml**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply run `mvn -f <archetypePomFile> archetype:update-local-catalog` doing a **mvn -f** pointing to the archetype pom.

So altogether it's:

1. Install archetype

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./my-archetype-1.0.jar -DpomFile=./my-archetype-1.0.pom
   ```
2. Update local catalog

   ```
   mvn -f my-archetype-1.0.pom archetype:update-local-catalog
   ```

Maybe that's obvious to others reading the doc but I spent enough time on this that I thought I'd write it up.

Comment: If this is still the best answer after the Bounty, then I guess I'll go ahead and accept it.  Thanks for the formatting edits.